# Python - Call a function of an object which is stored in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an Class which creates objects that contain a dict of functions. These functions are defined in the class.

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, name, functions):
        self.name = name
        self.functions = functions

    def myFunction1(self):
        print self.name
        return 'foo'

    def myFunction2(self):
        return 'bar'
```

In another file, I instance an object of the previous class and I want to run one of the functions that is in the dict.

```
from foo import Foo

myFunctions = Foo.('a name', {0 : Foo.myFunction1, 1 : Foo.myFunction2})

myFunctions.functions[0]()
```

I have this error :
TypeError: unbound method myFunction1() must be called with Foo instance as first argument.

I understand that when I execute the last line, I just call the function without call it with an object of Foo as first argument. But I can not write this :

```
myFunctions.myFunctions.functions[0]()
```

How can I call a function of this class which is stored in a dict attribute ?

Comment: What is `Foo` here? Do you mean it to be a class or should it be an instance? You don't need to resolve the method on the class *again*, you already have an unbound method (which includes a reference to the `Foo` class).

Comment: `myFunctions.functions[0](myfunctions)`? Also, no need for the `foo` module reference in your assignment, since your import statement of the form `from othermodule import name` adds `name` to the current module's namespace.

Comment: `Foo` is my class that create `Foo` objects. When I create a Foo object, I store in `myFunctions` attribute a dict of the functions that the object is supposed to use. The stored functions are defined in the same class than my object. I just want to call one of these functions by using the dict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not really understand what you are trying to achieve with this functions dictionary, but note that `instance.function()` is equivalent to `Class.function(instance)`. In the former, `instance` is implicitly passed as the `self` parameter; in the latter, you pass it explicitly.

Thus, you could try the following.

```
foo = Foo({0 : Foo.myFunction1, 1 : Foo.myFunction2})
print foo.functions[0](foo)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I replaced by Foo.functions[0](myFunctions)` (as `Class.function(instance`) and it works. I forgot this equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

You can call functions as a dictionary like this:

```
tmp = Foo()
tmp.functions={0:tmp.myFunction1, 1:tmp.myFunction2}
myFunctions = tmp.functions
print myFunctions.functions[0]()
```

Comment: It works when I don't pass self argument. But I need to use attributes of the object. I edit my question to be more comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an object method, best way is to write another function that will call the correct function

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, functions):
        self.functions = functions

    def myFunction1(self):
        return 'foo'

    def myFunction2(self):
        return 'bar'

    def run_func(self, func_key, *args, **kwargs):
        func_name = self.functions.get(func_key)
        if func_name and hasattr(self, func_name):
            return getattr(self, func_name)(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return None

fun_dict = {0:'myFunction1', 1:'myFunction2'}
a = Foo(fun_dict)
print a.run_func(0)
```

You can send even arguments in this way.

```
def myFunction1(self, name):
    return name

print a.run_func(0, "test")
```

This will print `test` by the myFunction1

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way to switch between functions:

```
       dict = {0 : Foo.myFunction1(), 1 : Foo.myFunction2()}
       function = fn_dict.get(0)
       function()
```